# Mobile P2P Charity App using Paypal - how to handle security

Tags: iphone, android, mobile, paypal

Merry Christmas, in the spirit of the season I had an idea of a peer to peer charity app for mobile platforms, where essentially you can go to find individual people who are in need of money and make a donation via Paypal to them.

It sounds pretty simple, but what I am concerned about is how to handle the Paypal side for the best security. I already know Paypal provides an approved SDK for use in mobile apps.

So how should I approach it? Should I have users create an account through the site, and provide their paypal email address in the account information (hidden from plain view) then when the other user wants to give to them, it would open the Paypal interface with that email address? Somehow that seems insecure.

What do you guys think?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can't speak for the android platform, but for the iPhone you're actually not allowed to process donations through the app. You **must** forward them completely out of the app to the paypal website. You can't even slide up a UIWebView in your app.